# CNN structure extension error (Error:Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node max_pooling2d_2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, artificial-intelligence, cnc

I would like to extend the CNN structure to the C-C-P-C-C-P-C-C-P structure. However, I get the following error: I can't do anything because it doesn't work, how can I fix this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Is there something wrong with my code? Is there any other way? How to solve it?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Dense,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# CIFAR-10 데이터셋을 읽고 신경망에 입력할 형태로 변환
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=cifar10.load_data()
x_train=x_train.astype(np.float32)/255.0
x_test=x_test.astype(np.float32)/255.0
y_train=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train,10)
y_test=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test,10)

# 신경망 모델 설계
cnn=Sequential()
cnn.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(32,32,3)))
cnn.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.25))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.25))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))

# 신경망 모델 학습
cnn.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])
hist=cnn.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=128,epochs=30,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),verbose=2)

# 신경망 모델 정확률 평가
res=cnn.evaluate(x_test,y_test,verbose=0)
print("정확률은",res[1]*100)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 정확률 그래프
plt.plot(hist.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('Model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train','Validation'], loc='best')
plt.grid()
plt.show()

# 손실 함수 그래프
plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train','Validation'],loc='best')
plt.grid()
plt.show()

# Train data의 20%를 validation set으로 설정
# 성능 평가는 test data만 이용
split_percent = 0.2
split_index = int(x_train.shape[0]*(1-split_percent))
x_t = x_train[:split_index]  #x_train
y_t = y_train[:split_index]  #y_train
x_v = x_train[split_index:]  #x_val
y_v = y_train[split_index:]  #y_val
```

ERROR :

```
Downloading data from https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz
170500096/170498071 [==============================] - 17s 0us/step
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
   1879   try:
-> 1880     c_op = pywrap_tf_session.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1881   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node max_pooling2d_2/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]](Placeholder)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,64].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
15 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
   1881   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
   1882     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1883     raise ValueError(str(e))
   1884 
   1885   return c_op

ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node max_pooling2d_2/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]](Placeholder)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,64].
```

This is the code I added.

```
# C-C-P-C-C-P
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Dense,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# CIFAR-10 데이터셋을 읽고 신경망에 입력할 형태로 변환
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=cifar10.load_data()
x_train=x_train.astype(np.float32)/255.0
x_test=x_test.astype(np.float32)/255.0
y_train=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train,10)
y_test=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test,10)

# 신경망 모델 설계
cnn=Sequential()
cnn.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(32,32,3)))
cnn.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.25))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dropout(0.25))
cnn.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))

# 신경망 모델 학습
cnn.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])
hist=cnn.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=128,epochs=30,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),verbose=2)

# 신경망 모델 정확률 평가
res=cnn.evaluate(x_test,y_test,verbose=0)
print("정확률은",res[1]*100)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 정확률 그래프
plt.plot(hist.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('Model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train','Validation'], loc='best')
plt.grid()
plt.show()

# 손실 함수 그래프
plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train','Validation'],loc='best')
plt.grid()
plt.show()

# Train data의 20%를 validation set으로 설정
# 성능 평가는 test data만 이용
split_percent = 0.2
split_index = int(x_train.shape[0]*(1-split_percent))
x_t = x_train[:split_index]  #x_train
y_t = y_train[:split_index]  #y_train
x_v = x_train[split_index:]  #x_val
y_v = y_train[split_index:]  #y_val




# C-C-P-C-C-P-C-C-P 구조
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Dense,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# CIFAR-10 데이터셋을 읽고 신경망에 입력할 형태로 변환
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=cifar10.load_data()
x_train=x_train.astype(np.float32)/255.0
x_test=x_test.astype(np.float32)/255.0
y_train=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train,10)
y_test=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test,10)

# 신경망 모델 설계
cnn=Sequential()
cnn.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(32,32,3)))
cnn.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.25))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.25))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,1)))
cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))

# 신경망 모델 학습
cnn.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])
hist=cnn.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=128,epochs=30,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),verbose=2)

# 신경망 모델 정확률 평가
res=cnn.evaluate(x_test,y_test,verbose=0)
print("정확률은",res[1]*100)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 정확률 그래프
plt.plot(hist.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('Model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train','Validation'], loc='best')
plt.grid()
plt.show()

# 손실 함수 그래프
plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train','Validation'],loc='best')
plt.grid()
plt.show()

# Train data의 20%를 validation set으로 설정
# 성능 평가는 test data만 이용
split_percent = 0.2
split_index = int(x_train.shape[0]*(1-split_percent))
x_t = x_train[:split_index]  #x_train
y_t = y_train[:split_index]  #y_train
x_v = x_train[split_index:]  #x_val
y_v = y_train[split_index:]  #y_val
```

Answer (score 2):

The input shape is (32,32,3) and you have multiple convolution and pooling layers. At each layer, the size of input shrinks. So, you should take care of the journey of your input through your layers. For example each pooling layers (2,2) makes the input half in size.

In your case, after `C-C-P-C-C-P` size of input will be (None,5,5,64) and feeding an input with (5,5) size to two other convolutional and then a maxpooling makes it size reduce to (1,1) and maxpooling can not take any action on the input of size (1,1). So, reorganize your layers and be aware or your input size and it's changes.

For example you can remove last `C-C-P` layers to avoid making the input much smaller.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Dense,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# CIFAR-10 데이터셋을 읽고 신경망에 입력할 형태로 변환
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=cifar10.load_data()
x_train=x_train.astype(np.float32)/255.0
x_test=x_test.astype(np.float32)/255.0
y_train=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train,10)
y_test=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test,10)

# 신경망 모델 설계
cnn=Sequential()
cnn.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(32,32,3)))
cnn.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.25))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.25))
#cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
#cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
#cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
```

You can check size changes by `model.summary()`:

```
model.summary()

Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 30, 30, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 14, 14, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 12, 12, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 10, 10, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 5, 5, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 5, 5, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1600)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               819712    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                5130      
=================================================================
Total params: 890,410
Trainable params: 890,410
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Your answer was helpful. I have a question, is it wrong to modify the pooling that comes at the end like cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,1))) because it has to be in the C-C-P-C-C-P-C-C-P structure?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, until get the minimum size which is 1,1 and try to shrink it more. If you check model summary printed above, you can see in the last layer before flatten layer (``dropout_3``) output shape is (5,5). You should just check the output shape of each layer once you modify your model structure to avid getting errors.

Comment: I need to compare the performance of the C-C-P-C-C-P structure and the C-C-P-C-C-P-C-C-P structure. Doesn't C-C-P perform better or not? I'm sorry that I keep asking questions because it's been a while since I've studied.

Comment: It depends. If you want your model to be larger, you can use another dataset which has larger size (such as 'cats_vs_dogs'), or you can resize your inputs to a larger size with ``tf.image.resize(image,(224,224))`` or you can use an ``upsampling`` layer after your input to make your data shape larger (like resizing image). There are many ways you can do so.

Comment: I added the code to the body, but when I run it, it is judged that C-C-P-C-C-P performance is better. Could the coding genius confirm if this is true? I'm so anxious.

Comment: As I said before, it depends. Not every deeper network gives you higher accuracy. You may get a better performance by shallowed networks. For example if you stack many layers and your input shape to 1,1, and most of data has been lost. so it has not enough data to pass to the dense layers for giving a good accuracy.